# bringing in an API (xml)/URL into php for Joomla

Tags: html, xml, api, joomla

what I need is a way to bring in this: 184.173.18.228/api/profile/1000/0/Adam.Adams  (which is an xml file) into php ( Im assuming) to be used in Joomla ( I can use Sourcerer for the code in Joomla) - the problem I have been running into is that there is a cross domain proxy problem - over last weekend I was able to render that xml when it was locally on my machine using ajax/jquery:

```
// jQuery script

$(function() {
    // Load data from proxy.php using GET request
    $.get('test.xml', function(data)
    {
        // Search for the XML element you want, perform an action on each occurrence of found element
        $(data).find("XMLElement").each(function()
        {
            $('#output').append($(this).attr('XMLAttribute')); // Display desired attribute of element -OR-
            $('#output').append($(this).children("Phone").text());
```

I'm not even sure if Im asking the question correctly -  what I would like to happen is: a php script to bring in that xml/url to echo/populate html on a page. I have tried a million things and just can't get it

Answer (score 0):

That really looks like Javascript, not php.  In php you wouldn't have the cross domain limitation anyway since it's running on the server, not the browser.

All browsers will block cross domain ajax calls.

Your solution is to write a script in php that does a wget or curl to the remote site, so you invoke a local script and the script on your server loads the remote url.  You should be able to find some ready-made.